# Inherit from generic class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.1

I have .net core 2.1 project. And my repository classes like below. But because of `MyDbContext` constructor has parameter, I'm getting error like below. When I remove JwtHelper parametrer, it is working perfectly. **But, I need adding `JwtHelper` in `MyDbContext.cs` for logging auditings.** How can I achieve this?

> 'MyDbContext' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'UnitOfWork'

**UnitOfWork.cs**

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork<TContext> where TContext : DbContext, new()
{ 
    protected readonly DbContext DataContext;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        DataContext = new TContext();
    }

    public virtual async Task<int> CompleteAsync()
    {
        return await DataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        DataContext?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**IUnitOfWork.cs**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork<U> where U : DbContext
{ 
    Task<int> CompleteAsync();
}
```

**MyRepos.cs**

```
public class MyRepos : UnitOfWork<MyDbContext>, IMyRepos
{
    private IUserRepository userRepo;
    public IUserRepository UserRepo { get { return userRepo ?? (userRepo = new UserRepository(DataContext)); } }
}
```

**IMyRepos.cs**

```
public interface IMyRepos : IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext>
{
  IUserRepository UserRepo { get; }
}
```

**MyDbContext.cs**

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IJwtHelper jwtHelper;

    public MyDbContext(IJwtHelper jwtHelper) : base()
    {
        this.jwtHelper= jwtHelper;
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var userId=jwtHelper.GetUserId();
        SaveAudits(userId,base.ChangeTracker);
        return (await base.SaveChangesAsync(true, cancellationToken));
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.cs**

```
public class UserRepository : Repository<User>, IUserRepository
{
    private readonly MyDbContext_context;

    public UserRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = _context ?? (MyDbContext)context;
    }
}
```

**IUserRepository.cs**

```
public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
{ }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IJwtHelper, JwtHelper>();
    services.AddScoped<DbContext, MyDbContext>();
    services.AddTransient<IMyRepos, MyRepos>();
}
```

Comment: Do you need the `new()` constraint on `TContext` parameter in the `UnitOfWork<TContext>` class? If so, you'll need to have a parameterless construction. You can have more than one constructor, btw.

Comment: So, `UnitOfWork` wants to run `DataContext = new TContext();`. Where is it meant to get a `IJwtHelper` from (if this were allowed to be parametrized)?

Comment: Thanks @CoolBots. I edited my question now by adding content of my UnitOfWork class. Can you check my UnitOfWork class? **Are there any different way `DataContext = new TContext();` ?** If is it possible, then I remove `new()` constraint.

Comment: Based on your code, you need the `new()` constraint, and a parameterless constructor in `TContext`. Perhaps `IJwtHelper` can be supplied some other way - as a property, for instance? Then it can be passed into the constructor of `UnitOfWork`, and set as a property on `TContext`

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I converted my UnitOfWork constructor to `public UnitOfWork(IAuditHelper auditHelper) { this.auditHelper = auditHelper; DataContext = new TContext(auditHelper);  }` . But,I'm getting  `'TContext': cannot provide arguments when creating an instance of a variable type` error. 
`

Comment: If you can pass parameters to your `UnitOfWork` constructor, just hand it an already constructed `TContext` and eliminate the `new()` constraint and that'll work.

Comment: Can I pass my JwtHelper from my startup.cs to UnitOfWork  or any other way? 
 @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Yes, but if you still want `UnitOfWork` to create the instance, passing the helper, you'll need to give it a `Func<IJwtHelper, TContext>` helper that can contain the specific `new` code that you cannot have inside the generic.

Comment: My aim is only logging audits by userId. I edited my question by adding all of my codes to my question. I also added my startup.cs. Where can I add `Func<IJwtHelper, TContext>` in my classes ?  @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the constructor of your `UnitOfWork`:

```
public UnitOfWork()
{
    DataContext = new TContext();
}
```

Here you construct a new object of class `MyDbContext` using a default constructor, but `MyDbContext` does not have a default constructor.

You decided to make your `UnitOfWork` very generic. That is great, because this enables you to use our `UnitOfWork` with all kinds of `DbContexts`. The only limitation you told your `UnitOfWork` is that your `DbContext` should have a default constructor.

A good method would be to create the factory yourself and pass it to the UnitOfWork.

If you don't want, or can't give `MyDbContext` a default constructor, consider telling your `UnitOfWork` how it can create one: "Hey unit of work, if you need to create the DbContext that I want you to use, use this function"

In fact, you will be using the [factory design pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm)

### Old fashioned interface method

Step 1: Create a class, with a function `Create()`, that will create exactly the DbContext that you want to use.

```
interface IDbContextFactory<TContext>
   where TContext : DbContext
{
    DbContext Create();
}

// The MyDbContextFactory is a factory that upon request will create one MyDbcontext object
// passing the JwtHelper in the constructor of MyDbContext
class MyDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
{
      public IJwthHelper JwtHelper {get; set;}

      public MyDbContext Create()
      {
           return new MyDbContext(this.JwtHelper);
      }


      DbContext IDbContextFactory<HsysDbContext>.Create()
      {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
  }
```

Step 2: tell your UnitOfWork how it should create the DbContext.

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork<TContext> where TContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public static IDbContextFactory<TContext> DbContextFactory {get; set;}
    protected readonly DbContext DataContext;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        this.DataContext = dbContextFactory.Create();
    }
    ...
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // create a factory that creates MyDbContexts, with a specific JwtHelper
    IJwtHelper jwtHelper = ...
    var factory = new MyDbContextFactory
    {
         JwtHelper = jwtHelper,
    }

    // Tell the UnitOfWork class that whenever it has to create a MyDbContext
    // it should use this factory
    UnitOfWork<MyDbContext>.DbContextFactory = factory;

    ... // etc
}
```

From now on, whenever a `UnitOfWork<MyDbContext>` object is constructed,
using the default constructor, this constructor will order the factory to create a new MyDbContext.

### Lambda expression

You don't really have to implement an interface. All that your UnitOfWork needs to know is how to create a DbContext.

Instead of an interface, you could pass it a Func:

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork<TContext> where TContext : DbContext 
{ 
    // use this function to create a DbContext:
    public static Func<TContext> CreateDbContextFunction {get; set;}
    protected readonly DbContext DataContext;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        // call the CreateDbContextFunction. It will create a fresh DbContext for you:
        this.DataContext = CreateDbContextFunction();
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // create a factory that creates MyDbContexts, with a specific JwtHelper
    IJwtHelper jwtHelper = ...
    var factory = new MyDbContextFactory
    {
         JwtHelper = jwtHelper,
    }

    // Tell the UnitOfWork class that whenever it has to create a MyDbContext
    // it should use this factory


    UnitOfWork<MyDbContext>.CreateDbContextFunction = () => factory.Create();
```

**Added after comment**

The part: `() => factory.Create();` in the last statement is called a lambda expression. It means: create a function without input parameters (that is the `()` part) and a double return value equal to `factory.Create()`.

### Bit off topic: explanation of Lambda expression

Similarly if you need to create a lambda expression that represents a function with input parameter a Rectangle and as output the surface of the rectangle:

```
Func<Rectangle, double> myFunc = (rectangle) => rectangle.X * rectangle.Y;
```

In words: myFunc is a function that has a Rectangle as input, and a double as output. The function is like:

```
double MyFunc (Rectangle rectangle)
{
    return rectangle.X * rectangle.Y;
}
```

You call it like:

```
Func<Rectangle, double> calcSurface = (rectangle) => rectangle.X * rectangle.Y;
Rectangle r = ...;
double surface = calcSurface(r);
```

Similarly, a lambda expression that represents a function with two input parameters and one output parameter:

```
Func<double, double, Rectangle> createRectangle = 
    (width, height) => new Rectangle {Width = width, Height = height};
```

The last parameter of Func<..., ..., ..., x> is always the return value

And for completeness: a method with a void return is called an Action:

```
Action(Rectangle) displayRectangle = (r) => this.Form.DrawRectangle(r);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @HaraldCoppoolse. I did your said. But when I add `UnitOfWork<MyDbContext>.CreateDbContextFunction = factory.Create();` to my `Startup.cs` class, I get error  **Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyDbContext' to 'System.Func<MyDbContext>**

Comment: Thanks a lot @HaraldCoppoolse. This is what I was looking for. You saved my a lot of time. It's worked perfectly. Only disadvantage of this approach is we creating a lot of ContextFactory. For example if we have 8 context, then will be `MyDb1ContextFactory, MyDb2ContextFactory,.....,MyDb8ContextFactory`. So, this is not generic. **Lastly, please add to MyDbContextFactory**  `DbContext IDbContextFactory<HsysDbContext>.Create() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }` for people who will see this post in future. Because class require implementation.

Comment: Well go ahead, edit the question. And of course you can make a generic function that instantiates a factory object that uses the correct constructor function, but that is worth a new question

Comment: I edited your answer. You are right. I will create new question for that now.

Comment: I create a new question go generic DbContextFactory @HaraldCoppoolse 
 .But, everyone opposed this UnitOfWork approach. They said that, you shouldn't use UnitOfWork. So, anybody don't answer my question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54749019/creating-generic-dbcontext-factory-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 1):

The `new()` constraint requires a parameterless constructor; however, since you need `IJwtHelper` in your `DbContext`, and that property only exists in `MyDbContext`, you can make your own base class to derive other contexts from instead of `DbContext`:

```
public class MyDbContextBase : DbContext
{
    public IJwtHelper JwtHelper { get; set; } 
}
```

- Remove `IJwtHelper` property from `MyDbContext`; remove the constructor; make it inherit `MyDbContextBase` instead of `DbContext`
- Change the `U` constraint on the `IUnitOfWork<U>` interface to `MyDbContextBase`
- Change `TContext` constraint from `DbContext` to `MyDbContextBase` on `UnitOfWork<TContext>` class; add `IJwtHelper` as a constructor parameter
- Once you instantiate a `TContext` in the constructor of `UnitOfWork<TContext>` class, assign `IJwtHelper` through the public property.

Comment: I added my all code as answer. I change my IJwtHelper  public from private as you said. And I added my `startup.cs.` But, I can't change TContext. Because it is dynamic. Forexample, 2 weeks later, I can create MyRepos2. If, I changed TContext, then I can use only one context. Can you edit my answer @CoolBots?

Comment: You can make `MyDbContext` a base class - just a `DbContext` with `IJwtHelper` property. You can then create sub-classes as needed, such as `class MyDbContext2 : MyDbContext`

Comment: Ok. I changed my question and I deleted my answer. @CoolBots

Comment: `class MyDbContext2 : MyDbContext` can be incorrrect. Because, MyDbContext2 and MyDbContext very different context. So, inherit from MyDbContext can be problem in future of project @CoolBots

Comment: I clarified my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helps @CoolBots. But, I can't achieve that way because of JwtHelper injection. HaraldCoppoolse's DbContextFactory solution is worked.