# Access services from DbContext in .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I have .NET Core 2.1 WebAPI project. I create base DbContext which name is `DataContext.cs`. I want to start `DataContext` by `IAuditHelper`. When project start, I can set `AuditHelper` from my **Startup.cs**.

But, after project start and execute `SaveChangesAsync` method, **it's being null.** How, can I achieve getting AuditHelper from My DataContext? (**I know, if I inject IAuditHelper in my DataContext constructor, then I can take. But, in that situation, Datacontext wants IAuditHelper in everywhere.**)

**DataContext.cs**

```
 public class DataContext : DbContext,IDataContext
 {
     public IAuditHelper AuditHelper { get; set; }

     public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
     {
         auditHelper.LogMyChangesToDatabase()
         return (await base.SaveChangesAsync(true, cancellationToken));
     }
 }
```

**IDataContext.cs**

```
public interface IDataContext : IDisposable
{
    IAuditHelper AuditHelper{ get; set; }
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<int> SaveChangesWithoutAuditAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

**UniversityDbContext.cs**

```
 public class UniversityDbContext: DataContext
 {      
    override protected void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
      optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=.; database=.; user id=.; 
            password=.;");
    }

    public UniversityDbContext() : base()
    {
    }
 }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IAuditHelper, AuditHelper>();
    services.AddScoped<IDataContext, DataContext>();
    services.AddScoped<DataContext, UniversityDbContext>();
    services.AddDbContext<UniversityDbContext>();
       

    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var dataContext = sp.GetService<IDataContext>();
    dataContext.AuditHelper = sp.GetService<IAuditHelper>();
}
```

Comment: Explicitly inject that dependency into the constructor of the context.

Comment: How can I do this @Nkosi .

Comment: While you can just inject this, I really think it's a bad idea. Why would you want to mix `HttpContextAccessor` with your `DbContext`?

Comment: Because, I want to logging database operation by CurrentUserId. So, I need JWT in my DbContext. @DavidG

Comment: Then I would advise you to inject a generic logging service, not a `HttpContextAccessor`.

Comment: I tried @DavidG. I create a `AuditHelper` and `IAuditHelper`. But, there was same problem in that. Because, I can't also access AuditHelper from my `DataContext`.  @DavidG

Comment: AddHttpContextAccessor() injects ContextAccessor, you don't need services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>(); ASP.NET Core dependency injection doesn't support property injection, you can use other containers instead, e.g. [Unity](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity) or [Autofac](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/index.html). What are you trying to achieve? It doesn't seem to be right from a design point of view.

Comment: I'm only want to achieve logging my Database operations by CurrentUserId @Kosta_Arnorsky . So, I need Jwt in my DataContext. If, are there any way for this, I can change my design.

Comment: I clarified my question changing `HttpContextAccessor` by `AuditHelper` @Kosta_Arnorsky @DavidG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Core dependency injection doesn't support property injection, you can instead inject dependencies into the constructor like it's shown below. Another option is to use containers that support property injection, like [Unity](https://unitycontainer.github.io/api/Unity.Attributes.DependencyAttribute.html) or [Autofac](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html).

```
public class DataContext : DbContext, IDataContext
{
    public DataContext(IAuditHelper auditHelper, DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
        AuditHelper = auditHelper;
    }

    public IAuditHelper AuditHelper { get; private set; }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        AuditHelper.LogMyChangesToDatabase();
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(true, cancellationToken);
    }

    ...
}

public interface IDataContext : IDisposable
{
    IAuditHelper AuditHelper { get; }

    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    ...
}

public class UniversityDbContext : DataContext
{
    public UniversityDbContext(IAuditHelper auditHelper, DbContextOptions options)
        : base(auditHelper, options)
    {
    }
}
```

I not quite understand why you need AuditHelper in IDataContext interface, I would save it in a private filed in DataContext and wouldn't expose it.

AuditHelper class:

```
public class AuditHelper : IAuditHelper
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public AuditHelper(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void LogMyChangesToDatabase()
    {
        //_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.
    }
}
```

In the Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    ...

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddDbContext<UniversityDbContext>(options
            => options.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=TestUniversity;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"));
        services.AddScoped<IAuditHelper, AuditHelper>();

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

You can find difference between scopes at [the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes).

A controller:

```
public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UniversityDbContext _context;

    public SomeController(UniversityDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
        ...
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

I also recommend to follow [TAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) and change LogMyChangesToDatabase:

```
    public async Task LogMyChangesToDatabase()
    {
        //_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.
        //await 
    }
```

SaveChangesAsync will be accordingly:

```
    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        await AuditHelper.LogMyChangesToDatabase();
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(true, cancellationToken);
    }
```

And the connection string of cause should be in the config, [see tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2#register-the-schoolcontext).

Comment: Thanks @Kosta_Arnorsky.  Firstly, I created my structure like you said. But, I took `'MyDbContext' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'UnitOfWork'` in my `MyRepos.cs` class. So, I want to create my DataContext constructor without parameter. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54741937/inherit-from-generic-class my question.

Comment: As it's said in the answer to your question, you can use an abstract factory/delegate to create a context. Could you please clarify, why do you need UnitOfWork? Are you  trying to create a processing pipeline?

Comment: Thanks @Kosta_Arnorsky. I think there is no other way of doing this by ASP.NET Core dependency injection. So, I will use DbContextFactory.